# How to debug @type problems

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-completion, type-hinting

I have created a folder `types` and put a file `models.d.ts` in there which has this content:

```
import * as loopback from 'loopback';

declare namespace Models {
    export class BaseModel extends loopback.PersistedModel {
        public createdAt: Date;
        public updatedAt: Date;
    }

    export class Document extends BaseModel {
        public id: number;
        public name: string;
        public type: string;
        public currentState: number;
        public loanrequestId: number;
        public isLocked: boolean;
        public comments: string[];
        public hasMedia: boolean;
    }
}
```

I have added the loopback typings:

```
typings install dt~loopback --save
```

When I try to type a variable to `Models.Document` vscode still claims that the varbiale is of type `any`:

```
/** @type {Models.Document} document */
let document = await Document.findById(id);
```

If I remove the import line and remove `extends loopback.PersistedModel`  document is correctly typed.

How can I archive that I can subclass `BaseModel` from `loopback.PersistedModel`?